# How to create a copy of the slot with createElement?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How to access name of the component of the slot?

I want to create a copy of the component provided in the slot:

```
const child1 = slot
const child2 = h(???, slot.props)
```

So that `child1` renders exactly as `child2`.

I need this, so that I can change properties of that VNode, for examples classes.

#### Context

```js
import { h } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    const children = [];

    for (const slot of slots.default()) {
      const child = h(???, slot.props)
      children.push(h('div', [child]));
    }

    return () =>
      h('div', children);
  },
};
```

#### Background

I want to make a component similar to [q-button-group](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button-group):

I need 2 components `TButton` and `TButtonGroup` so that I can style `TButton` independently and create groups just by putting those buttons inside the `TButtonGroup`.

#### Example

```html
  <TButtonGroup>
    <TButton label="Two" />
    <TButton label="Three" />
  </TButtonGroup>
```

`TButton` should have a different list of classes:

- when it's inside TButtonGroup: `px-4 py-2`
- when it's not: `border rounded-lg px-4 py-2`

[See full html](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z5uN88Mk7b)

#### Playground

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-button-group-razbakov?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGroupRender.js

Comment: Please, explain what exactly you want to do, it's unclear from the question. What do you need a name for?

Comment: @EstusFlask I want to change component from slot. Use case: https://dev.to/razbakov/vue3-challenge-buttonsgroup-4dfo

Comment: I'm not sure how it correlates with the post you linked.  There's TButton component, why shouldn't it be rendered as is? By the way, questions need to be fully understandable without navigating to external links, this is required by SO rules. Please, explain your case in details. I suspect that current attempt on slots is XY problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask I added more context

Comment: You have control over TButton, don't you? The most straightforward way is to make it change classes depending on a prop and provide this prop when it's inside TGroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component name of vnode won't tell much, components are already resolved at this point. VNode's element or component is stored in `type` property.

The problem with your approach is that render function is an alternative to component template, not a way to access the entire DOM element hierarchy. There will be no `TButton` child elements like `div` in render function, only `TButton` vnode itself. It needs to be rendered in order to access its children.

If `TButton` were someone else's component which initial behaviour needs to be modified, this could be done by adding some directive to it and accessing component's children elements.

But since `TButton` is your own component that can be modified to your needs, the most straightforward way is to make it change classes depending on a prop and provide this prop when it's inside `TGroup`, i.e.:

```
const child = h(slot.type, {...slot.props, group: true}, slot.children);
children.push(child);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer to my initial question is `h(slot.type, slot.props, slot.children)`. That's what I was looking for. I was debugging and looking for a string that says `TButton`, but I had to look for object that is marked as VNode, i.e. `type`. It wasn't clear in the official documentation. Background and examples are unrelevant to initial question, it's just one use-case I invented to better understand how to work with render function.

Comment: You're welcome. It looked like you tried to change TButton's internal structure (div), but in case you don't then that's the answer indeed. The string is probably `slot.type.name === 'TButton', but you'd have to resolve 'TButton' string to the component any way in order to use with `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the component type you created:

```js
const { h } = Vue

const TBtn = {
  props: {
    staticClass: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div
      class="t-btn px-4 py-2"
    >
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `
}

const TBtnGroup = {
  setup(props, {
    slots
  }) {
    const children = [...slots.default()]
      .map(slot => h(slot.type, {
        class: ['border', 'rounded-lg']
      }, slot))

    return () => h('div', {
      class: ['d-flex']
    }, children)
  },
}

const App = {
  template: `
    <t-btn>OUTSIDE 1</t-btn>
    <t-btn>OUTSIDE 2</t-btn>
    <br />
    <t-btn-group>
      <t-btn>INSIDE 1</t-btn>
      <t-btn>INSIDE 2</t-btn>
      <t-btn>INSIDE 3</t-btn>
    </t-btn-group>
  `
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App)
app.component('TBtn', TBtn)
app.component('TBtnGroup', TBtnGroup)

app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.px-4 {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.py-2 {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rounded-lg {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}

.t-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I accepted the other answer, because it helped me to understand why I couldn't find solution myself. Your solution would help too, but there are few moments: (1) it should be other way around: inside without border, outside with border and (2) it should use tailwindcss, i.e. I wanted to use existing classes and find a way to solve it without writing additional css. The button-group-component challenge could be solved without render function just with css.